# Error creating bean .Error in FindBy method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, crud

DTO

```
@Entity(name = "EnumMaster")
public class EnumMaster {
    @Id
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="pg-uuid")
    private UUID EnumerationID;
    private String Name;
    private String Text;
    private String Description;

    public EnumMaster(){}
    public EnumMaster(UUID enumerationID) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.EnumerationID= enumerationID;

    }
    public EnumMaster(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.Name= name;

        }
.
setter getter
.
```

Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/retrivefromPublicationDropDown", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
        public @ResponseBody
        ArrayList getPublicationStatus(NativeWebRequest req) {
            ArrayList<EnumValue> arrayList = new ArrayList<EnumValue>();
            Collection<EnumMaster> enumMaster;
            try {
                String name = "ePublicationStatus";
                enumMaster=enumMasterRepository.findByName(name);
}
}
```

Repository

```
public interface EnumMasterRepository extends CrudRepository<EnumMaster,UUID>{
    Collection<EnumMaster> findByName(String name);

}
```

Error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dropDownController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.dts.adminportal.service.DropDownService com.dts.adminportal.controller.DropDownController.dropDownService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dropDownServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.dts.adminportal.repository.EnumMasterRepository com.dts.adminportal.service.DropDownServiceImpl.enumMasterRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enumMasterRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.dts.adminportal.service.DropDownService com.dts.adminportal.controller.DropDownController.dropDownService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dropDownServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.dts.adminportal.repository.EnumMasterRepository com.dts.adminportal.service.DropDownServiceImpl.enumMasterRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enumMasterRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dropDownServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.dts.adminportal.repository.EnumMasterRepository com.dts.adminportal.service.DropDownServiceImpl.enumMasterRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enumMasterRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:876)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.dts.adminportal.repository.EnumMasterRepository com.dts.adminportal.service.DropDownServiceImpl.enumMasterRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enumMasterRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enumMasterRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1442)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:876)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.unknownAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.locateAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:189)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toExpressionRecursively(QueryUtils.java:408)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.build(JpaQueryCreator.java:197)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.toPredicate(JpaQueryCreator.java:144)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:86)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:44)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:109)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:98)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:60)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:279)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:147)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:153)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:43)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    ... 66 more
```

I am new to programming. So can any one please tell me what is wrong in my code and how to remove it.I am not sure but its giving me null point exception right? though I am sending name but still cant cant understand what is the error

Comment: My bet is that the error is caused by your incorrect naming of the fields in the entity: `Name` should be `name` (same for the other ones). Respecting standard conventions is crucial, even more when you use tools like Spring data which relies on these conventions.

Comment: Could you also post your configuration?

Comment: @JBNizet In my db the fields are as follows
enumerationid,
description,
name,
text
......
And i change my FindByName to FindByname still its giving me same error.

Comment: @geoand configuration means my pom.xml file right sorry to bump with such stupid question

Comment: I mean your Spring configuration (either XML or Java Config classes). However I agree with JB Nizet, the problem is probable that you have 'Name' as a field instead of 'name'

Comment: You shouldn't rename the method to findByname(). You should rename the **field of the entity** from `Name` to `name`.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of u.I renamed the feild From Name to name and problemed Solved